# Can we use document.getElementById() dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to print an html page using window.print. Where as the html page is getting updated for each rest API call. so can i print continuously for each rest API call???

```
    var myPrintContent = document.getElementById("data-box"); 
    var myPrintWindow = window.open('','Print-Window');
    var popupWindow = window.open('','Print-Window');
    popupWindow.document.write('<TITLE></TITLE>\n');
    popupWindow.document.write('<URL></URL>\n');
    popupWindow.document.write('<script>\n');
    popupWindow.document.write('function print_win(){\n');
    popupWindow.document.write('\nwindow.print();\n');     
    popupWindow.document.write('}\n');
    popupWindow.document.write('<\/script>\n');
    popupWindow.document.write('</HEAD>\n');
    popupWindow.document.write('<BODY onload="print_win()" >\n');         
    popupWindow.document.write(myPrintContent.innerHTML)
    popupWindow.document.write('</BODY>\n');
    popupWindow.document.write('</HTML>\n');
    popupWindow.document.close();
```

This is what i am doing. so content of data-box.innerhtml is different for different employees. So on each time i call print one page i will get. But for the next employee if i am again calling the print function the called employee details is only getting printed. So what i want is if i gave different id s for different employees, how can i get all the ids dynamically. so that once i call print i can get all the data s of all employee printed.

Comment: so you want the same printContent be printed multiple times?

Comment: No the content keeps on changing for each api call

Comment: are you trying to say innerHtml of the element

Comment: yes. i am doing id.innerhtml @ Krishjs

Comment: can you write more of the code and give what your api is returning?

Comment: Please add more information. In general there is nothing preventing you from re-querying the element over and over printing it's new content...assuming that is what you want to do. You only have shown the one line, are you re-querying the element with each API call? If not, then the moment the next API call over-writes that element (assuming that is what is happening, need the code for that) your `myPrintContent` is not going to refer to the same element anymore and needs to be re-queried but there isn't enough info in the question to make a concrete call on that.

Comment: Any help will be great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.print();
```

as can be read at[w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp) is a method to print the current window. It has nothing to with document.getElementById() method. 
If your are interested in printing your page, simple print the window. That's it.

But if you want to use document.getElementById() for some other purposes, you can pass variable (the dynamic id) of element in consideration.
here is how you do it

```
var myId = "my-element-id";
var myContent = document.getElementById(myId).innerHTML;
```

Better post any code for better help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..So lets assume i have 14  different ids. So can i print all these id s dynamically by calling print function one time.

Comment: I have not tried but I hope you can. All you need to do is put those ids in array and loop through it. print should be within loop at the end

Comment: How that can be done? Since i am getting id and then i am writing in to html page, where it is on load calling window.print . So if i put it in the for loop also the last id is only  getting printed.